# How do I prevent windows from moving when the desktop resolution changes?

Tags: linux, resolution, xorg, desktop, openbox

I'm running Linux and use Openbox for my desktop. Normally the desktop resolution is 1280x1024. However, when I play a game which only plays at a specific resolution, at fullscreen and there's no options menu, and exit it, windows outside the bounds of the in-game screen resolution have been moved to within those bounds.
I wanted some method (preferably, if possible, changing a setting somewhere) of preventing windows from being moved in this way.